# C++ vector of vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to write a program that uses a base class to define an algorithm for solving a simple problem. I use a vector of ints as a 'game board'. My question is how can I create a function get_moves that returns a vector of game boards?

Here is the code I have for the function:

```
std::vector< <std::vector<int> > takeaway::generateMoves( std::vector<int> currBoard ) {


    if( currBoard[0] == 1 || currBoard[0] == 2 ) {
       moves.push_back( 1 );
    }
    else if( currBoard[0] == 3 ) {
       moves.push_back( 2 );
    }
    else if( currBoard[0] == 4 ) {
       moves.push_back( 3 );
    }
    else {
      moves.push_back( 1 );
      moves.push_back( 2 );
      moves.push_back( 3 );
    }

    std::vector< <std::vector <int > > toReturn( moves );

     for( int i = 0; i < moves.size(); i++ ) {

      std::cout << "MOVES: " << moves[i] << std::endl;
    }

  return toReturn;
```

The errors that I get are:

takeaway.cpp:55: error: template argument 1 is invalid
takeaway.cpp:55: error: template argument 2 is invalid

So my question is how can I properly create and return a vector of vectors?

Answer (score 5):

You have too many <'s on your template declarations.

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > takeaway::generateMoves( std::vector<int> currBoard ) 
{

    if( currBoard[0] == 1 || currBoard[0] == 2 ) {
       moves.push_back( 1 );
    }
    else if( currBoard[0] == 3 ) {
       moves.push_back( 2 );
    }
    else if( currBoard[0] == 4 ) {
       moves.push_back( 3 );
    }
    else {
      moves.push_back( 1 );
      moves.push_back( 2 );
      moves.push_back( 3 );
    }

    std::vector< std::vector<int> > toReturn;
    toReturn.push_back( moves );

     for( int i = 0; i < moves.size(); i++ ) {

      std::cout << "MOVES: " << moves[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return toReturn;
}
```

There might be more, but that is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to construct the `vector` of `vector<int>` using only a `vector<int>`.  Cannot see how `moves` is declared but based on the rest of the code, I would think this will work.

```
std::vector<std::vector <int > > toReturn;
toReturn.push_back(moves);
```

Don't see the value in using `vector` of `vector`s here, but perhaps this is a partial sample.

Also - passing in the board by reference instead of by value would be more efficient, since this avoids the entire thing being copied. You are not altering it so `const` reference is better.

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > takeaway::generateMoves( 
    const std::vector<int>& currBoard )
```

Returning by value (ie vector< vector as your return value) is probably OK since this code will likely by optimized to avoid taking a copy of `toReturn` according to the [NRVO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364057%28VS.80%29.aspx).

An alternative would be to pass in a non-const reference to the required structure, which should be empty on entry to match current logic:

```
void takeaway::generateMoves( 
    const std::vector<int>& currBoard, std::vector< std::vector<int> >& toReturn )
```